# Get current GridView column value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have GridView with some of columns. all the columns are boundfield like:

```
            <asp:BoundField DataField="orderId" HeaderText="orderId" 
            SortExpression="orderId"></asp:BoundField>
```

The last column is:

```
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"    
  CommandName="" onclick="LinkButton1_Click" Text="Button"></asp:LinkButton>
```

as you see , there is "onclick" with some method.. like:

```
        lbltest.Text = gv_order.Rows[gv_order.SelectedIndex].Cells[2].Text;
```

With that code i get (offcourse) what i have on the selected row in cell number 2. how can i get value from the same row (and from cell number 2) where the button is clicked without the "selceted row" ? example: when i click button on row 2 - i get the cell 2 of that row.

That's possible?

Comment: What datafield is bound to the cell 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retrieve 'orderid' in more clean way, you can use `CommandName`, `CommandArgument` properties and `OnRowCommand` event like this:

```
        <asp:GridView (...) OnRowCommand="Gv_RowCommand" (...)>

...

        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Select"
     CommandArgument='<%# Bind("orderId") %>' Text="Button"></asp:LinkButton>
```

and in code behind:

```
protected void Gv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Select")
    {
         int selectedOrderId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
         // ... 
    }
}
```

I hope this is what you want to do.

**Edit - my answer to your comment:**

Then, it's little more complicated and uses 'selectedRow' in some way. In my own code, I use this approach:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gv1" (...) DataKeyNames="orderId,email,username"
         OnRowCommand="Gv_RowCommand" (...)>

            ...

    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Select"
       CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,"RowIndex") %>' Text="Button">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

and in code behind:

```
protected void Gv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int selectedRowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    if (e.CommandName == "Select")
    {
         int orderId = Convert.ToInt32(gv1.DataKeys[selectedRowIndex]["orderId"]);
         string email = gv1.DataKeys[selectedRowIndex]["email"].ToString();
         // ... 
    }
}
```

Comment: What i can to do if i need more than one datafield? exemple: orderId, email, username ? how can i write that?

Comment: I've just answered to you comment in question.

Comment: I'm appologaize about all the questions.. i got now error: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException about the index size.. i've tried to change the size and still get the error

Comment: @Bside, which statement throws this error? What is the value of index?

Comment: The error for :  lbltest.Text = gv_order.DataKeys[selectedRowIndex]["txId"].ToString(); 
the value is string.

Comment: @Bside, do you have "txId" listed in DataKeyNames of GridView? This error appears only to "txId"?