# LinkButton on GridView - after selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I asked the next question:

[Get current GridView column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704185/get-current-gridview-column-value)

And i got the right answer. now i want - that after click on the linkbutton that i have there - the text of the button will change to: "done" or  its visble will be false.

how can id to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if referencing to the same answer, you can do something like

```
protected void Gv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int selectedRowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    var row = Gv.Rows[selectedRowIndex ];
    var btn = row.FindControl("LinkButton1") as LinkButton;
    if(btn != null)
    {
       btn.visible = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. work great. how can i do with your answer or with other idea - that after click on that button - he forever will be visble = false ? (even after page refresh)? i thought about sql but i dont know how to do the sql statement for the linkbutton click when he is on grid view. i thought to add to the sql table bit column and when the linkbutton clicked the bit column will be true. and then to do your code with example: if(bit column == true) .. btn.visble - false.

Comment: if you are unsure about that, make visible = true when you defining the link button

Answer (score 0):

In `RowCommand` event handler,

```
LinkButton button=e.CommandSource as LinkButton;
button.Text="Done";
```

Answer (score -2):

on click event of linkbutten...

```
protected void lnkDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lnkbtn = (LinkButton)sender;
    lnkbtn.Text = "Done";
}
```

Comment: you cant write onclick event to the button which inside the gridview.

Comment: @kasun you answerd here for my qustion from your comment? after then i need to get the bit column of the same row with "WHERE" clause.. but don't know how to relate that for the correct row